# How to create incremented view filters for numeric fields in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, filter, drupal-7, drupal-views

In my Drupal 7 I'm building a view of homes/properties with exposed filters of "Minimum Rent" and "Maximum Rent" - so that people can find homes according to their budget.

Rent (per month) is basically an integer field and can be whichever number (£475 or £677 or whatever).  But in my exposed filters for "Min Rent" and "Max Rent" I want it to be a dropdown list of £100, £200, £300, £400, £500 etc - incremented.  Exactly as we see on websites like www.rightmove.co.uk or www.zoopla.com or any other property listing website.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do this without custom coding.
I would do it like this:

- alter the exposed form
- add a new dropdown with your incremented values: 100, 200, etc.
- on the page, hide the Min Rent and Max Rent (from css).
- use a javascript code to sync your dropdown with MinRent and MaxRent. For example, when 100 is selected, set MinRent=100 and MaxRent=199.

When user selects a value from DropDown and submits, the view will get the 100-199 values and filter the results accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Ionut.A  - I've coded a small custom module which I've posted here http://drupal.org/node/1557994  ... it works almost perfectly, but because I don't know how to set the default values for numeric integers, on  first pageload the Views keeps giving me "An Illegal Choice" error.